# Can we assume independence of random variables?

Tags: probability

I have the following problem I want to solve: Let $\delta,\varepsilon>0$ and $X_n$ a sequence of non-negative random variables such that $P(X_n\geq \delta)\geq \varepsilon$, show that with probability one $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n = \infty$.

I solved this problem very easily by assuming the $X_n$ to be independent. Essentially the argument is to consider $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X_n\geq \delta) = \infty$ and so by Borel-Cantelli Lemma we have that $P(X_n\geq \delta ~ \text{i.o.})=1$. From where it follows that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n = \infty$ since infinitely many of the $X_n\geq \delta$ with probability one.

But in the problem there is no mention of independence. I believe one can do the following, tell me if this is a legitimate step. Construct a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ with a sequence $Y_n$ of *independent* random variables on $\Omega$ so that $X_n$ and $Y_n$ induce the same distributions i.e. $P(X_n\in A) = \mu(Y_n\in A)$ for any set $A$ of real numbers. Thus, even though the problem never says to assume the $X_n$ are independent we may assume that anyway.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your approach does not work. While you can indeed construct such a sequence of independent random variables, the distribution of their partial sums will depend on their joint distributions, which you would change.

But the result is wrong. Let $X$ be a random variable that is $0$ with probability $1/2$ and $1$ with probability $1/2$. Let $X_n=X$ for all $n$, so that they are perfectly correlated. Let $\delta<1$ and $\epsilon<1/2$.

Comment: Thank you for the response. 

I checked the errata for the textbook and it does indeed say that we need to include "independent" before saying "non-negative". 

Can you elaborate more on "the distribution of their partial sums will depend on their join distributions which could change"?

Comment: @ILoveMr.Paul The problem is simply that it is possible that $X_1$ and $Y_1$ have the same distribution and $X_2$ and $Y_2$ have the same distribution, but $X_1+X_2$ and $Y_1+Y_2$ may not. For example, simply let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be the same coin flip, but let $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ be independent coin flips.